# Convert decimal to binary combination (of custom lenght)

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I need to convert several decimal numbers (or a string or 1 and 0) to a binary combination. In .NET I see many libraries working with Byte. A Byte is a manipulation of 8 bits. In my case I have to work with set of 3 bit that I need to concatenate together.

For example:

[image]

for Filter or Partition I have a 3 position bit.

What should I use to help me for this kind of conversion? At this moment I try to understand BitArray but I don't understand how to create bit a specific size then fill them easily.

Here is what I already did

```
    BitArray headerBits = new BitArray(new bool[] { false, false, true, true, false, false, false, false }); // 8
    BitArray filterBits = new BitArray(new bool[] { false, true, true });  // 11
    BitArray PartitionBits = new BitArray(new bool[] { true, false, true });  // 14
    BitArray CompanyPrefixBits = new BitArray(new bool[] { false, false }); // 16
```

Let's try with these 16 first bits. The result I want is

[image]

```
 3074
```

EDIT ------

```
BitArray headerBits = new BitArray(new bool[] { false, false, true, true, false, false, false, false }); // 8
BitArray filterBits = new BitArray(new bool[] { false, true, true });  // 11
BitArray PartitionBits = new BitArray(new bool[] { true, false, true });  // 14
BitArray CompanyPrefixBits = new BitArray(new bool[] { false, false }); // 16

BitArray newBitArray = new BitArray(headerBits.Cast<bool>()
.Concat(filterBits.Cast<bool>())
.Concat(PartitionBits.Cast<bool>())
.Concat(CompanyPrefixBits.Cast<bool>())
.ToArray());

var byteArray = newBitArray.ToByteArray();
Console.WriteLine($"{BitConverter.ToString(byteArray, 0)}");
// Result is 0C-2E
// I expect 30-74
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve or set Filter and Partition?

Comment: I added an example of what I want

Comment: So you're trying to display the data as text either in hexadecimal, decimal, octal or binary format?

Comment: The screenshot come from the Windows Calculator but i'm only interested by hexadecimal

Answer (score 1):

> I try to understand BitArray but I don't understand how to create bit a specific size then fill them easily.

`BitArray`has several constructors. The most obvious is to create the `BitArray` from a `bool` array:

```
var bits = new BitArray(new[] { true, false, true, true });
```

The other approach is to create an uninitialized `BitArray` just by the size constructor and then setting the bits one by one:

```
var bits = new BitArray(4); // 4 bits, all false for now
for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
    bits[i] = GetMyNextBit();
```

**Update:**

If your main issue is to convert the concatenated bits into bytes you had better you use one big `BitArray` for all the fields.

After you set all of the bits you can use this extension method:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this BitArray bits)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[(bits.Length - 1) / 8 + 1];
    bits.CopyTo(result, 0);
    return result;
}
```

> i'm only interested by hexadecimal

You can easily convert the bytes into hex string:

```
var result = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    result.Append(bytes[i].ToString("X2"));
```

Comment: I also don't know how I can concatenate my bits vraiables

Comment: Here is a solution for concatenating `BitArray`s: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518513/is-there-any-simple-way-to-concatenate-two-bitarray-c-net

Comment: +1 @taffer. Bastien, if you're dealing with a BitArray then you'll need to decide how you handle a size that is not divisible by 16 if you're looking to display the result in hex.

Comment: The concatenation works but I still cannot convert properly to hexa. I edited my question with the code I use. the result and my expected result.

Comment: It seems endianness is not what you need. If you insert `Reverse` after the concatenated bits as well as the converted bytes you get 3074. I created a fiddle, see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eALFeD - EDIT: a single reverse is enough if you use `Insert` into position 0 instead of `Append` when creating the hex result (fiddle modified).

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're reading data from an RFID tag.
All data can be treated as a series of bytes, hence the examples using bytes.

If the data is to be displayed as a string in hexadecimal format then I would suggest that you read the data into an array and then use

`System.Convert.ToString(data, base);`

where data is your 16 bit value and base can be 2,8, 10, 16 for binary, octal, decimal or hexadecimal.