# Is there an easy way to merge several BitArrays?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitarray

I have several BitArrays that will need to be merged to into 48 byte structure.

```
BitArray a1 = new (3);
BitArray a2 = new (11);
BitArray a3 = new (14);
//And so on

//Do bit manipulation, etc with the individual Arrays.
```

Ultimately, I want appended all the together and return a byte[] so I can send them out via UDP. I was thinking of keeping them in an array / list of just iterate thru them and dump them into an ulong - > byte[]

Comment: if you need special grouping, you have to precise how you would to group your BitArray to build 6 bytes of 8 bits or another type of building

Comment: Just some considerations: Is the data inteded to be sent / received _much_ more frequently than operated on (calculations / modifications / read-write-access) or is the data by far more "used" than transmitted? **If** you send it _much_ more often than you operate on it, you may want to consider choosing a byte-format to begin with and map access/modification operations around that. That way you avoid highly frequent conversions which _may_ (or may not) accumulate runtime/memory.

Comment: @Fildor The data is a header protocol. I need to append this header to every message that gets sent out, frequency varies, but no faster than 1hz.   Also all messages received will have this header, so I will need to decode the incoming byte[] into each a1. You think I am better off using byte shifting operations?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518513/is-there-any-simple-way-to-concatenate-two-bitarray-c-net), there isn't really a better way to concatenate two `BitArray`s than just "doing it step by step" - make a `bool[]` for the result, copy each `BitArray` into there, and then make a new `BitArray` from the `bool[]`.

```
BitArray ConcatenateAll(params BitArray[] arrays) {
    var bools = new bool[arrays.Sum(a => a.Count)];
    var index = 0;
    foreach (var array in arrays) {
        array.CopyTo(bools, index);
        index += array.Count;
    }
    return new BitArray(bools);
}
```

Since you want a `byte[]`, you can do:

```
var bitArray = ConcatenateAll(bitArr1, bitArr2, ...);
var bytes = new byte[48];
bitArray.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
```

Note that you can also convert the `bool[]` directly into a `byte[]` by bit operations if performance is important, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24322811/5133585).

Comment: @wohlstad Ah I see. The alternative would be to do some bit shifting and ANDing, in order to turn `bool[]` into a `byte[]` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24322811/5133585).

Comment: I thought simple copies into a `byte[]` will do (like in my posted answer). Am I wrong ?

Comment: @wohlstad I don't think that works. The second argument for `CopyTo` refers to an index of the destination array. This means you can't copy to a position *inside a byte*. I don't think the OP wants all the bit arrays to be aligned at byte boundaries. That's how I understand the word "appended" in the question.

Comment: You are absolutely right. +1. It was my mistake (and I deleted my answer).

Comment: I was wondering if OP shouldn't keep the data in a transmissible datastructure (`byte[]`) to begin with and taylor access / modification operations around that? - Unfortunately that's not an answer to the question but maybe a solution to the _problem_?

Comment: Could use `int[]` or `byte[]` arrays also, see the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray.copyto?view=net-8.0#remarks but you would need whole 8- or 32-bit boundaries in each original `BitArray`